# output time in hh:mm:ss format relative to how many seconds

Tags: javascript

I have created a function within **JavaScript** which converts seconds to the format `hh:mm:ss`. It works fine at the moment, however, I'd like it to be a little bit more *refined* than it currently is.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
convertTime(secs){
    var sec = parseInt(secs, 10),
        hours = Math.floor(sec / 3600),
        minutes = Math.floor((sec - (hours * 3600)) / 60),
        seconds = sec - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if(hours < 10){ hours = "0" + hours; }
    if(minutes < 10){ minutes = "0" + minutes; }
    if(seconds < 10){ seconds = "0" + seconds; }

    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

// this will output 00:02:03
convertTime(123);
```

However, I would prefer the returned outputs to be something along the lines of this instead:

> 11 -> 0:11
>
> 60 -> 1:00
>
> 1200 -> 20:00
>
> 3600 -> 1:00:00
>
> 36000 -> 10:00:00

I have made countless attempts at creating (and finding) a function which can do something similar, but all **JavaScript** conversions I've come across (and / or made) are always done in the format `hh:mm:ss`, or are just output incorrectly.

All help is really appreciated,
Cheers.

Comment: Probably because everybody expects 0:11 to be 11 minutes after midnight. Your suggested output is non-standard and misleading. Maybe you should rethink whether you really want to have it this way.

Comment: @str I forgot to mention that this is for a video player :) It's how YouTube, Facebook and Twitter do it - so it shouldn't be that misleading

Comment: Well, fair point ;)

Comment: @str Hahaha, I thought so too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your return statement to

```
return parseInt( hours ) > 0 ? ( hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds ) : ( minutes + ":" + seconds ) ;
```

Simply don't return `hours` if `hours` is not greater than `0`

In case, your `minutes` need to be trimmed if there are no `hours` then update your padding logic to

```
if(hours > 0 && minutes < 10){ minutes = "0" + minutes; }
```

Comment: Ah yes, see while you're almost right, I've already attempted this :/ and while it **sorta** works, there's always that leading `0` (ie: `02:40` and `02:01:00`

Comment: Thanks for the answer though! :D appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

A more compact version of @gurvinder372 response

```
return (parseInt(hours) > 0 ? hours + ":" : "") + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```